# Configuring the webserver on a production site for Symfony

Tags: deployment, symfony1, symfony-1.4, httpd.conf, dev-to-production

I am setting up my Symfony project on the production site. @ this point it states:

This project uses the symfony libraries. If you see no image in this page, you may need to configure your web server so that it gains access to the symfony_data/web/sf/ directory.

Which basically means, I need to get into httpd.conf file and make some changes (for those who have diligently followed the Symfony tutorials, you guys know what I am talking about). Given this situation, I am not sure how I can go about configuring the httpd.conf file on the production server.

Anyone have any strategies around this? Thanks,

Parijat

Comment: What exactly are you afraid of / is blocking you ?

Comment: actually I have had it posted online, and managed to get some success. Right now facing a 500 internal server error not found.

Comment: any clues on that? can't access my httpd.conf file since it's not my computer but I do have a dedicated server that is hosting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding symbolic link from your symfony_data/web/sf to web/sf but your web server must follow symbolic links or you can add "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks" in to your .htaccess